# Showing the contents of a cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to extract an array in MATLAB such as below:

[image] 
Before this i used regular expressions to split particular delimiters among the columns.

Code : `datasplitnew = regexp(replacefinal, '\,', 'split');`

In the end, i would like to show the contents of that cell array accordingly among its respective columns in that same cell array. I know that i can just click the cell array that i would like to view and see the contents, but i don't want that.

Some people have been telling me to use, `{:}` to split the cell array, but it only seems to split the first row in the column instead of all of them.

Please advise.

Comment: What does "decell" mean? Can you give a MWE with some expected output for a given input?

Comment: change the topic of the question. i would just like to show the contents of a cell array within a cell array among its respective columns.

Comment: I still find the question somewhat vague.  Can you put up dummy data set that shows what you mean and what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply concat them as rows have different number of cells.

The ones that have the same number you could join with vertcat.

But in the end the only solution I can think of is to construct the table cell by cell. but that's not hard to do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `char(datasplitnew)` to get one big character array.